# требуется помощь в написании макроса для excel

Tags: excel, vba, макросы, макрос, imacros

Имеется выгрузка задач в файле эксель. Необходимо отсортировать задачи по параметру "название отделения" (столбец G). Создать файл эксель по "названию отделения" в папку в корне диска С:. Скопировать строки относящиеся к каждому отделению в файл с названием отделения. Заранее благодарен.
[image: Общий вид выгрузки задач]
[image: Деление выгрузки на файлы]
[image: Скопированные данные в файл]

Comment: Помочь-то с чем? Если сделать по ТЗ, то Вы не туда обратились, работа не на 10 минут. Ищите фриланс-площадки (или пишите на почту :) )

Comment: Подскажите в какие функции копать. Я конечно не понимаю, как все делать, но хочу разобраться.

Comment: Сортировка, создание файла, копирование данных в файл - три разных задачи. ищите информацию отдельно, так легче будет понять и применить на практике

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать расти над собой!